# Cross origin Framing in Java Script

Tags: javascript

I want to put google.com or any other site like facebook or youtube in one iFrame but it is giving me error saying "Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=8sd0VLaQKKyH8QfYx4CwDg&gws_rd=ssl does not permit cross-origin framing."

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error or how to put google.com into my own iframe.

Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If the origin you are trying to load doesn't allow itself to be included in an iframe, you can't include it in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If the X-Frame-Options response header is set to `Deny`, it can't be rendered in a frame at all. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options